# PHP Speed - Many Echos vs Building a String

Tags: php, string, performance, echo

Wondering if anyone knows if either of these methods would produce an output faster:

```
Method 1
for ($i=1;$i<99999;$i++) {
echo $i, '<br>';
}
```

or

```
Method 2
for ($i=1;$i<99999;$i++) {
$string .= $i . '<br>';
}
echo $string;
```

Thanks for any input you have.

Comment: Who cares? If anything, there will be difference of a few microseconds. If you care about speed, use something like Java.

Comment: I would say, if you care about speed use something like C ;)

Comment: @Felix - But C sucks (truth!), and isn't a web language.

Comment: @Coronatus: I absolutely disagree. C is one of the most important languages, even (and especially today). It is just a matter of learning it, but lets start not a flame war here :)

Comment: re: using a different language... In the few years it will take you to learn and implement another language which is believed to be more efficient for this purpose just to shave off a microsecond, the purpose of your application will be long gone, and even more efficient languages will have popped up by then anyway.  The number of layers to add and manage on the software stack just to print "hello world" on the client's machine is also apparently irrelevant to some folks here, so why not just go with assembly?

Comment: @Bob - it should never take an even half-decent programmer that long to learn a language to a good degree, especially using a framework.

Comment: @Coronatus: perhaps someone should run some benchmarks on this: a test, from scratch to output, to see which is the faster method.  I have a hunch Op's example 1 would win within 5 minutes, example 2 coming a fraction of a millisecond later, C several weeks, Java not coming in at all because server admins won't respond to your request to set it up, and assembly just giving up because you can't find a way to just execute it.  Meanwhile, client is just sitting there the whole time patiently waiting for just some sort of server response.

My whole point is, comparing apples and oranges is noise.

Comment: @Coronatus: Right, and implementing java helps to answer OP's question of which PHP method is faster how?

Comment: @Bob - Nobody said anything or cares about implementing it. The only thing I and the other posters care about here is the speed difference and attacking your silly comments.

Comment: @Coronatus: `Who cares? If anything, there will be difference of a few microseconds. If you care about speed, use something like Java. – Coronatus`.  But you're right though - my sarcasm isn't adding anything positive here, so I apologize and will stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method 1 seems like it'd be faster. Method 2 will have to spit out a bunch of `CONCAT` opcodes for each iteration of the loop, and the very long string will be built in memory until you're ready to send it. Method 1 on the other hand will just be two `ECHO` opcodes per loop, and then PHP/your webserver is free to flush content to the client before you've fully finished, if it wants to.

Of course, if you're concerned about micro-optimisation, you're going to get far better performance by using an opcode cache, caching proxy, or something like [hiphop](http://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php).

Comment: while then again the output operationis quite complex and depending on the server SAPI jsut filling a buffer, so the second approach might be the cheaper way to create a buffer ... maybe ob_start() and buffering that way is better ... there are many variables involved and I could come up with benchmarks proving every approach "better" :-p But it's useless ... use a profiler, identify the bottleneck, improve there. No micro-optimisation.

Answer (score 4):

Method 1 Uses less Memory and CPU and is "faster" (Less server load)
But the output bottleneck most likely is the browsers downloadspeed.

If you don't buffer the output, the browser can start downloading stylesheets, images, etc sooner.
 (while your script is waiting for some query results)

Check out the answers on [PHP Optimalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127765/php-optimization-tips) or http://code.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-php.html for more tips.

Comment: Not sure if method 1 is faster since it uses a comma as concatenation operator.

Comment: @Alix Using multiple parameters for echo (the comma) is supposed to be faster than first concatenating and then echoing.

Comment: Yes, but the second example uses a faster concatenation operator: the `.`. From some benchmarks I've seen using `,` instead of `.` decreases "significantly" the performance.

Comment: I have tested it. 262.240 cells out of 32.780 records processed and displayed on single web page. Results: 
Method 1: 12.633333206177sec, Method

Comment: I have tested it. 262.240 cells out of 32.780 records processed and displayed on single web page. 
Results: 
Method 1: 12.633333206177sec
Method 2: 12.42796587944sec

Answer (score 0):

I have read that the fastest method is to enable [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) and do many echoes.
I don't have benchmarks to confirm this claim, though.

Anyway, I think this is in the realm of micro-optimization.  The difference is probably measurable, but insignificant.  As @Coronatus comments above, if your app were that sensitive to performance, you wouldn't be using PHP!

Comment: "if your app were that sensitive to performance, you wouldn't be using PHP" Tell that to Facebook ;-) There always ways to make PHP better

Comment: @Italy Moav - Yes they do, but PHP is only used for frontend work at Facebook. Official languages there are C++, Java and PHP. Chat (the most resource-intensive) is done in C++. Lots of good articles about performance at highscalability.com

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to micro-optimise, look to changing $i++ to ++$i as well